# PTIJ: Why was spread created during Erev Shabbat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Pirkei Avot 5:6 says:

עשרה דברים נבראו בערב שבת ... והשמיר

"10 things were created on Erev Shabbat. (among the list is) the schmeer ("spread" - as in "a schmeer of cream cheese on the bagel."

Why were spreads specifically created on Erev Shabbat? If it was so that you could use it as part of the Shabbat meal, I don't see the purpose of that as it is a *melacha* (*memarech*) to spread on Shabbat.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 6):

Because on Friday everyone is busy preparing for shabbos and don't have time to make a proper lunch, so God in his infinite wisdom and kindness gave us the Shcmeer so we can quickly make a sandwich and continue preparing for shabbos.

And we see in Sotah 48b,

> ת"ר שמיר שבו בנה שלמה את בהמ"ק

King Shlomo utilized the efficiency of the Spread to speedily build the Beis Hamikdash by distributing sandwiches with spreads to all his workers.

Answer (score 3):

It was necessary in order to prepare for the obligation to eat bagels (a strange form of bread, often called textually, לחם משֻנה, lechem m'shuneh) on Shabbat.